# I've upvoted, but no hats on Movies.SE

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

Since yesterday I've upvoted several answers and questions, but I have yet to receive either Witticism or Jammin Out.  I have, however, received several other hats on Movies.SE.

Comment: You upvoted other people's questions, or you have been upvoted by others? The hats in question are for your questions and answers being upvoted (i.e. posting 5 or more questions/answers which have scores of 1 or more), not for upvoting others.

Comment: See [Ambiguity in hat description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159180/169404)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have **your** questions or answers upvoted to get the hats. (For these)

- `5 questions with score of 1 or more`
- `15 questions with score of 1 or more`
- `30 questions with score of 1 or more`
- `5 answers with score of 1 or more`
- `15 answers with score of 1 or more`
- `30 answers with score of 1 or more`

However, you can get this hat by using 10 upvotes in a day :

- `cast 10 upvotes in a single day`

Except for that one (`A Need For Speed`) , Upvoting or Downvoting other's question won't get you any hats... or will it ? ;)

Comment: There's one hat for using 10 upvotes in a day.

Comment: ooooh, i've been reading those wrong, ok.

Comment: Oh you're right forget about this one. I took for granted that he was talking about the hat i'm refering too in my answer :)