# "question w/ X views" hats

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

The Guide my Sleigh, Soup du Jour, and Buddy Breathing hats come from asking a question with 50, 250, and 500 views respectively.

This is a little vague (much like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159180/169404)).

- Does it have to be asked **after** Winter Bash started?
- Can an old question qualify if it reaches these # of views **during** Winter Bash? (so excluding any questions already above these numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All questions and answers have to be posted after the winter bash started. A moderator pointed that out [on my question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159136/winter-bash-hats-delay).

```
All other hats must be earned by actions performed between 00:00 UTC 19 December 2012 and 23:59 UTC 4 January 2013. Happy hat-hunting!
```

The "other" refering to the L'Chaim hat which is the only hat you can get retroactively.

Comment: This is not necessarily true for *all* hats. I earned a hat for an answer I had posted in November. ;) But all the ones that are visible to you follow this criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Only on questions since December 19th